# what does ":" after parameter name means?

Tags: .net, syntax

I have a c# method:

```
public void foo (DateTime toDate) { ... }
```

when I invoke that method, visual studio intellisense suggest an option of

```
foo (toDate :    )
```

What does that syntax mean ? sending anonymous var ?

Thanks for any clarification

Comment: It doesn't suggest that for me.  And that is invalid syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are for named parameters. See also http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2009/01/22/c-4.0-named-parameters-for-better-code-quality.aspx

So you can pass the arguments by name in any order you like. This is new in the C# 4.0 compiler.

Answer (score 4):

This syntax is used with [Named and Optional Arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx).

Comment: +1 for linking to the documentation instead of just a random blog post :-)

Answer (score 1):

Is a [named argument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx), so you can pass an argument referencing it by name instead of just position. In order to me is just a way to mess up a former elegant language, but this is just an opinion :)